# Conda working but could not create virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm having problems setting up a virtual environment with Conda. Conda is working (I guess) when I tried commands such as `conda --version`.
But when I tried `conda create -n mynewenv python=2.7` I got an error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 74, in _main
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.common._os.linux'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1291, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1006, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1050, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1061, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1116, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .base.context import context
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.common._os.linux'
```

I tried and search online for errors involving the said module `conda.common._os.linux` but could not find any. I would like to know where can I get this module or should I reconfigure conda? The server is currently using Python 3.6.7 and Conda 4.6.14.

### UPDATE

Apparently conda is not working. I get the same error message with any other conda arguments such as `info` and `list`. The only working arguments are `-h` and `-V` to check help message and version check. How can I reconfigure conda? This is on a shared server.

Comment: have you checked the `.bashrc` file to see if conda is inizialized? On install it adds some commands  (`# >>> conda initialize >>> ...`)

Comment: @Albo Yes. I already initialize it with `conda init`. Interesting to note is that when I use `sudo conda`, I was able to run the command. It doesn't work if I run it as a normal user.

Comment: did you use `sudo` first hand to install `conda`? Is `conda` in your home directory? You can check the conda executable path using `echo $CONDA_EXE`... maybe it's not in your home directory?

Comment: This is a shared server, so `conda` is installed at root level. Previously other users were able to use `conda`, but I'm not sure what settings did I accidentaly changed. I wanted to know how to setup so that other users can use `conda` as well.